# Passing JobID to Matlab Script (not Function) in Submitting Multiple Jobs

Tags: linux, matlab, terminal, jobs, qsub

In my main script, I call a function and within that function I call stata (with system command) where it takes input from matlab and then matlab calls the output of this stata command. I want each of these input and output files have a unique JobID. (I can give other unique IDs with datetime etc, but I don't want this.) I want JobIDs like 1,2,3...

I am using a cluster environment and PBS file to add details about my submit.  I want this PBS file take the JOBID from my first step and then send it to the matlab script.

My steps are as follows:

1- write a .py script for multiple jobs (I first try for #2 jobs)

```
#!/bin/env python
#PBS -A open
import csv, subprocess
for i in range(1,3)
    qsub_cmd = """qsub -F JOBID = {jobid} submit_m3.pbs""".format(jobid=i)
    print(qsub_cmd)
    exit = subprocess.call(qsub_cmd, shell=True)
```

2 - Write pbs file called submit_m3.pbs (I need to pass JOBID here)

```
 #!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -l walltime=48:00:00
#PBS -l pmem=10gb
#PBS -A open
# Load in matlab
module purge
module load matlab
cd ~/code
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash < myScript.m > log.myLog  
# JOBID must be placed somewhere in the above line.
```

3- Call the .py script in Linux terminal

```
python myPyFile.py
```

In the step 2, instead of the line starting with matlab, I also tried this (following other community questions)

```
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "job_id=${JOBID};run('myScript.m');exit;"
```

but this code didn't pass JOBID to my script.
So, 2 things need to be solved. Passing JOBID to .pbs file and then to matlab file. Once it is in matlab, the rest (stata part) is OK!

Comment: Bash uses `$JOBID`, not `${JOBID}`. You might also need to remove spaces around the equal sign in `qsub -F JOBID = {jobid}`, not sure about that.

Comment: Instead `matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "job_id=${JOBID};run('myScript.m');exit;"` do `matlab -batch "job_id=$JOBID; myScript"`

Comment: Regarding the spaces, you are right. There is actually no space but I guess while copying they are created. I just submitted job with "matlab -batch ..." , will update here

Comment: the jobs ended quickly w/o running matlab. must be an issue with the command.

Comment: The `-batch` option exists since MATLAB R2019a, I believe. I assumed you have the newest version on your cluster, but maybe you have an older one? In any case, try to run the command locally first, it's much easier to debug things that way.

Comment: Hi. I tried batch option with job_id =1. It is working. But when I tried $JOBID or ${JOBID}  the code doesn't run.

Comment: That tells me that the `JOBID` variable is not being set. I don’t know `qsub`, or what HPC environment you are running this on. I found [this documentation](https://www.jlab.org/hpc/PBS/qsub.html), if it corresponds to your system then you should not use a `-F` option, which doesn’t exist, and instead use `"""qsub -v JOBID={jobid} submit_m3.pbs"""`.

Comment: Let me quickly try that.  another quick thing, when I want to do this "job_id=1; ../myscript" I am getting error 'invalid use of operator' with the arrow pointing to the dots. I tried using single and double quotes but didn't work. Do you know how to change the dir while using -batch command? Thanks

Comment: Either do `run('../myScript.m')`, or add the directory where the script is to your path (`addpath('..'); myscript`), or switch directories so the script is in your working directory (`cd('..'); myScript`).

Comment: Here we go. It is working well, now, when I changed to -v. Thanks Cris, you saved my day.